# Match a structure against set of patterns

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm

I need to match a structure against set of patterns and take some action for each match.

Patterns should support wildcards and i need to determine which patterns is matching incoming structure, example set:

```
action=new_user email=*
action=del_user email=*
action=* email=*@gmail.com
action=new_user email=*@hotmail.com
```

Those patterns can be added/removed at realtime. There can be thousands connections, each have its own pattern and i need to notify each connection about I have received A structure which is matching. Patterns are not fully regex, i just need to match a string with wildcards * (which simple match any number of characters).

When server receives message (lets call it message A) with structure `action=new_user email=testuser@gmail.com` and i need to find out that patterns 1 and 3 are matching this message, then i should perform action for each pattern that match (send this structure A to corresponding connection).

How this can be done with most effecient way? I can iterate this patterns and check one-by-one, but im looking for more effecient and thread-safe way to do this. Probably its possible to group those patterns to reduce checking.. Any suggestions how this can be done?

**UPD**: Please note i want match multiplie patterns(*thousands*) aganst fixed "string"(actually a struct), not vice versa. In other words, i want to find which patterns are fitting into given structure A.

Comment: regex library?  Prob. best.

Comment: Can you clarify: first, I see 4 patterns, and I think that 1 + 3 match (not 1+2). Second, do you just need a yes/no answer (=there is at least one pattern matching), or do you need an answer like: pattern x, y are matching, the rest is not? Third, is the set of patterns fixed, or can it be any set? Fourth, what is your pattern  language: match each symbol exactly, but match any string for *? Or is it a more general regular expression?

Comment: what kinds of wildcards does your pattarn support? if * is the only one then you can write simple loop to verify such patterns. If you need regular expressions then use regex lib.

Comment: @PSIAlt: Shouldn't pattern 3 also match to the example that you have given?

Comment: @Zane Sorry about this mistake. 1+3 should match. And yes, i need to take some action for each matching pattern (send this struct to corresponding connection). Edited post to note that.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the patterns to regular expressions, and match them using [RE2](http://code.google.com/p/re2), which is written in C++ and is one of the fastest.

Comment: Probably this can be part of problem solution

Comment: For higher speed, you may want to create a single regular expression, e.g. `(pattern1)|(pattern2)|...` and after matching it you can retrieve which of the patterns matched. You will get only one of them though: if pattern1 and pattern2 both match, you'll get only pattern1.

Comment: yes, but i need to find all patterns which is matching and take an action for each (send data to corresponding socket)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if I understood correctly, the fourth pattern is redundant, since the first pattern is more general, and includes every string that is matched by the fourth. That leaves only 3 patterns, which can be easly checked by this function:

```
bool matches(const char* name, const char* email)
{
    return strstr(name, "new_user") || strstr(name, "del_user") || strstr(email, "@gmail.com");
}
```

And if you prefer to parse whole string, not just match the values of `action` and `email`, then the following function should do the trick:

```
bool matches2(const char* str)
{
    bool match = strstr(str, "action=new_user ") || strstr(str, "action=del_user ");
    if (!match)
    {
        const char* emailPtr = strstr(str, "email=");
        if (emailPtr)
        {
            match = strstr(emailPtr, "@gmail.com");
        }
    }
    return match;
}
```

Note that the strings you put as arguments must be escaped with `\0`. You can read about `strstr` function [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/).

Comment: Sorry i did not mention that patterns can be added/removed at realtime. There can be thousands connections, each have its own pattern and i need to notify each connection about I have received this structure(which is matching).

Answer (score 0):

This `strglobmatch` supports `*` and `?` only.

```
#include <string.h>  /* memcmp, index */

char* strfixstr(char *s1, char *needle, int needle_len) {
  int l1;
  if (!needle_len) return (char *) s1;
  if (needle_len==1) return index(s1, needle[0]);
  l1 = strlen(s1);
  while (l1 >= needle_len) {
    l1--;
    if (0==memcmp(s1,needle,needle_len)) return (char *) s1;
    s1++;
  }
  return 0;
}

int strglobmatch(char *str, char *glob) {
  /* Test: strglobmatch("almamxyz","?lmam*??") */
  int min;
  while (glob[0]!='\0') {
    if (glob[0]!='*') {
      if ((glob[0]=='?') ? (str[0]=='\0') : (str[0]!=glob[0])) return 0;
      glob++; str++;
    } else { /* a greedy search is adequate here */
      min=0;
      while (glob[0]=='*' || glob[0]=='?') min+= *glob++=='?';
      while (min--!=0) if (*str++=='\0') return 0;
      min=0; while (glob[0]!='*' && glob[0]!='?' && glob[0]!='\0') { glob++; min++; }
      if (min==0) return 1; /* glob ends with star */
      if (!(str=strfixstr(str, glob-min, min))) return 0;
      str+=min;
    }
  }
  return str[0]=='\0';
}
```

Comment: Sorry i doubt this bruteforce way will be enough to match many patterns several times a second

Comment: Measure it before judging it based on intuition. If you replace strfixstr with an optimal substring search (e.g. Knuth--Morris--Pratt), the algorithm of strglobmatch is actually optimal (O(glob_len + str_len)), and the implementation is straightforward and fast.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i should check many patterns for each string this way, so its far heavier than `O(glob_len + str_len)`

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is wildcart matching, then you might try this algorithm. The point is to check all substrings that is not a wildcart to be subsequent in a string.

```
patterns = ["*@gmail.com", "akalenuk@*", "a*a@*", "ak*@gmail.*", "ak*@hotmail.*", "*@*.ua"]
string = "akalenuk@gmail.com"
preprocessed_patterns = [p.split('*') for p in patterns]


def match(s, pp):
    i = 0
    for w in pp:
        wi = s.find(w, i)
        if wi == -1:
            return False
        i = wi+len(w) 
    return i == len(s) or pp[-1] == ''

print [match(string, pp) for pp in preprocessed_patterns]
```

But it might be best to still use regexp in case you would need something more than a wildcart in a future.